# Is anyone use Activecollab with Git or Hg?

Tags: git, mercurial, git-svn, hgsubversion, activecollab

We currently use activecollab with subversion, but we want to consider using Git or Hg to give us distributed source control.

Is anyone making this work, so that revisions can be linked to tickets in activecollab, just as they are for SVN?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

activeCollab 3 (currently in [beta](http://www.activecollab.com/forums/forum/28/)) has built in GIT and Mercurial support.

Due to the way you authenticate on GIT repository and limitations of most production PHP setups, activeCollab works only with local copies of repository. Unlike SVN, where you can just provide repository URL and user credentials, for GIT you need to:

1. Clone a repository on the same machine where activeCollab is installed,
2. Set up cron to auto-update it
3. Add path of the local repository copy to activeCollab.

When activeCollab 3 stable version is out, we'll provide documentation and detailed instructions.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to host private git. you can use [gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite) and [activeCollab gitolite module](https://rtcamp.com/activecollab-gitolite/)

This module will allow to manage git repos, SSH Keys, Read/Write access & more from activeCollab source module page.

Answer (score 1):

There is no official support for Git or Mercurial with ActiveCollab yet, as illustrated by [this thread](http://www.activecollab.com/forums/post/25340/) or [this one](http://www.activecollab.com/forums/post/29472/).

May 2010:

> Sorry, I haven't heard of anyone providing GIT support for activeCollab's Source module.
>   We'll consider development of such integration as core feature, but since we don't use GIT ourselves, it may take a while (there are also some more important task on our to do list at the moment).

Jan. 2011:

> Sorry, we don't comment on features that are not yet part of activeCollab, until they are part of activeCollab. If we add this to the system, we'll let everyone know about it, don't worry.

There is a [post-receive hook for activeCollab written in PHP to be used with Git & Github](https://github.com/scottkf/github-activecollab-hook), which illustrates some form of collaboration between AC and Git, but that's about it.

Comment: Has anyone used that hook, or git-svn? I read the code for that but still wasn't quite sure what it did. The SVN integration is nice because it allows you to see diffs quickly, which I find great for reviewing code.

Comment: @Terence: good question, I don't have a direct experience with it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a pretty stable module https://github.com/UCF/ActiveCollab-Github-Module/
You just need to fix the issue when after installing it https://github.com/UCF/ActiveCollab-Github-Module/issues/1#issuecomment-1969986

Hope it will help you.